# Why does my custom checkbox not correctly propagate change value if I set the type after view init?

Tags: angular, forms

I am writing some wrappers for normal form controls in my angular app by writing components / directives that have selectors like 'input[custom-input]'. By doing that I am able to setup public methods that can later be used when doing content projection.

My Html then looks like

```
<a-component-that-handles-animating-placeholder-etc>
    <input custom-checkbox formControlName="field"/>
</<a-component-that-handles-animating-placeholder-etc>
```

The advantage here is that the input is available directly to any component that might want to use it, whereas if I wrote a wrapper I would have to implement a pipeline for every functionality such as disabled e.g

```
<custom-input [disabled]="isDisabled"]></custom-input>
```

Another advantage is that I do not have to implement new custom control value accessors to bind formcontrolName on and make the framework happy, when in reality the implementation of custom-input would be to just internally use input, which for every control adds a lot of complexity to the project.

The problem is that the reactive form control is not being updated with the correct value when the checkbox is checked and unchecked. In my custom component with this selector `input[custom-checkbox]` I am doing this logic:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'type', 'checkbox');
  }
```

Thats because I dont want consumers to have to specify that this element is a checkbox twice like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" custom-checkbox/>
```

But for some reason setting the type after the render is breaking the event that updated the form control. I have no idea why.

EDIT: I forked one of the stackblitz and replicated my problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzqp4k

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz so it can be more clear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that the Angular framework declares how to deal with form controls before host binding kicks in which means that for checkboxes the listener for its value has already been setup to point to input.value, and later changing the input type doesnt change the listener.

From what I have tried I think there is no real solution, you just have to ensure the control has a type for your ks-checkbox directive / component. You can do that using the parentElement property if you DI the elementRef.

Answer (score 1):

Following your blitz (& mine), I remembered that inputs are already managed by angular forms. You can control them through `NgControl`.

[Here is the result](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxhbhm?file=src/app/input-wrapper/input-selector.directive.ts)

```
export class InputSelectorDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.type') inputType: string = "checkbox";

  ngControl: NgControl;

  constructor(
    private R: Renderer2,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.ngControl = injector.get(NgControl);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.inputType = "checkbox";
    this.ngControl.control.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.elRef.nativeElement.checked, { emitEvent: false }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Someone just advised me that the way angular declares a control behaviour is before the hostbinding decorators are checked.

I tried implementing this and of course for that reason valueChanges doesnt fire - because it is listening for value to change, not checked.

The solution seems to be changing the selector to [appInputSelector][type="checkbox"] in order to ensure it is used correctly, but this is not really a solution. I dont think there is one.

P.S. because the component in question is already an input, it is already a control, so you can DI NgControl directly.

Comment: @Craig hence my solution with `NgControl`. Have you tried ?

Comment: sorry edited my comment - yes tried as described in comment

Comment: Thanks for the help - I appreciate you took the time :)

Comment: @Craig force of habit ahah, indeed you can DI it directly. But are you satisfied with that answer ?

Comment: I am not satisfied but I think its the best I can do. In my situation where I need direct access to the input HTML I dont think this is possible to achieve due to the order angular sets things up.

Comment: @Craig well you have access to your native input with this solution

Comment: Since this answer didnt work for me, but it lead me to the problem of the framework actually having to have the type supplied early in its loading lifecycle, I havent marked it as the answer but I awarded the bounty since you helped me a lot.

Thanks again

Comment: @Craig well no problem and thank you, if you have another issue feel free to create a new question and notify me of it !

Answer (score 0):

You don't even to go though that pain.

Simply use `HostBinding` to bind on `attr.type`, and on init, set it to checkbox.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brgcx5?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-wrapper%2Finput-selector.directive.ts)

```
export class InputSelectorDirective {

  @HostBinding('attr.type') inputType: string;

  constructor(
    private R: Renderer2,
    private elRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputType = "checkbox";
  }
}
```

Comment: This didnt work for me unfortunately, but I did go and make a new stackblitz demo based on yours that replicates the problem.

Comment: @Craig what do you mean it doesn't work ? I see two checkboxes in your blitz.

Comment: below the checkboxes I am rendering the 2 form controls values, you will find that clicking one checkbox changes the rendered value for that field, but clicking the other does not.

Comment: I see, then you will need to implement the control value accessor interface to be sure it works as expected !

Comment: @Craig I have created another answer that should resolve your issue, and yes you're right, but that doesn't prevent you from creatinc custom controls !

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set these attributes manually when using Reactive Forms. You just need to add the  `formControl` Directive and it will handle the rest for you!

Snippet from the Angular `checkbox_value_accessor` source code:

```
/**
* Sets the "checked" property on the input element.
*
* @param value The checked value
*/
writeValue(value: any): void {
this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'checked', value);
}
```

And a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6hryh) to see it in action

Comment: I dont want to make a custom form control for an existing control, as in my experience it leads to opinionated code that on a large project ends up being a pain.

All I really want here is a very thin layer so my checkbox can tell my wrapper when to animate a placeholder and so on.